# Rails - jQuery Geocoding and Places autocomplete plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm trying to use the aforementioned plugin for an Events app I'm building using Ruby On Rails but I can't get it to work. 
The purpose of the plugin will be to assist the user by auto-completing the location address when creating/editing a new event.

This is my events.coffee file -

```
jQuery ->

 $("#datepicker").datepicker(dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy");

jQuery ->

$('geocomplete').geocomplete()

$.fn.geocomplete 'geocomplete'
```

Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I've also downloaded the jquery.geocomplete.js & jquery.geocomplete.min.js and added them to my javascript folder.

This is my _form.partial.html.erb with geocomplete identifier -

```
<%= f.input :image, as: :file, label: 'Image' %>
<%= f.input :title, label: 'Title' %>
<%= f.text_field :location, id: 'geocomplete', label: 'Location' %>
<%= f.text_field :date, id: 'datepicker', label: 'Date' %>
<%= f.input :time, label: 'Time' %>
<%= f.input :description, label: 'Description' %>
<%= f.input :organised_by, label: 'Organised by' %>
<%= f.input :organiser_description, label: 'Organiser description' %>
<%= f.input :url, label: "Link to Organiser site" %>

<%= f.button :submit, label: 'Submit' %>
```

This is my application.html.erb with google api link -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MamaKnows</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-        track' => true %>
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places">      </script>
  <script src="jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<header>
```

Any assistance as to why this isn't working would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I've got it working.

All that was needed was the following adjustment to the application.js file as documented -

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.geocomplete

$(function() {
$("#geocomplete").geocomplete();
});
```